# ReactJS Material UI component css classes, clarification

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I understand that to style Material UI components I should use their `useStyles`, like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(themes => ({
    root: {
        marginTop: '15px',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: '0'
    },
    menuButton: {
        color: grey[800],
    },

  }));
```

but I'm not sure about why. For example, what if I want to use the same css on several components? Wouldn't it be easier to have a separate css file?

Comment: you can export them and reuse in other components, that way you end up with only 1 `makeStyles` function.

Comment: Something like export const useStyles and then import them where I need them?

Comment: yes thats what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there any advantage in using this rather than a css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export them and reuse in other components, that way you end up with only one `makeStyles` function which you can probably place in some unified file of styles.

```
  export const useStyles = makeStyles(themes => ({
    root: {
        marginTop: '15px',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: '0'
    },
    menuButton: {
        color: grey[800],
    },

  }));
```

Why would you do this:
Its a theme based component, say it as you have global theme of using blue buttons but then you are overriding it with green but keeping fonts and other stuff inherited from the theme or possibly discarding entirely.

This method is possibly preference based (and in case your repo is following `CSS in JS` style and you dont want to mix up CSS) but if you want to enforce styled component in your library then you would use this method on the component which is contained within the component.

You can think of this method as taking in `themes` and then passing in modifier to the theme that you want to override for the component that uses `useStyles` class.

With that said, you can use it as CSS class as well in your component.

Answer (score 1):

no you can import it in other files where you need it.

suppose you need root style in another View.jsx example file. then import useStyles to that View.jsx file and then you can use all its classes in that View.jsx file.